# How to save multiple plots in a for loop without overlapping data?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm saving plots in every iteration of a for loop, but for some reason the after the first plot, the rest of the graphas are overlapping, hence I can see on the last graph all previous graphs overlapped.

[image]

I'm using the following function in order to save the plots.

```
def plotStats(aggr_ep_rewards, i, my_file):
    '''Plot rewards curves'''

    DIR = '../Simulations/2_Q_Learning_exploration_explotation/A/'
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['avg'])#label="average rewards"
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.title(f"RL Q_Learning TEST:{i}")
    plt.xlabel('Episodes')
    plt.ylabel('Rewards')
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(DIR, my_file))
```

Am I missing something? How to obtain individual grapsh for each iteration?

Comment: try using `plt.figure()` before the call to `plt.plot`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it!!!!